# Should I inform my manager at current internship that I will be interviewing for my next internship?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, job-change, internship

EDIT: This has been flag as duplicate, however the other post does not address the context of 1) internship and 2) no overlapping conflict (I am not leaving a job for another). While I understand that I don't need provide any justification to my employer,  my concerns are regarding the necessary professional courtesies.

I am currently a month-in my internship with a great team and manager.

I recently got invited to an interview at a big 4 software company and might have to miss time at my current work to attend it. This interview will be for my next internship.

Should I inform my current manager about it, and to what extend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to put in "reason" when asking for days off for job interview at another place?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/89716/what-to-put-in-reason-when-asking-for-days-off-for-job-interview-at-another-pl)

Comment: If the other internship would start after the end of this one (as opposed to having to leave one for the other), there probably isn't much harm in telling them, but there also isn't much benefit to doing so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I tell my internship employer I am going to a university career fair?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98411/should-i-tell-my-internship-employer-i-am-going-to-a-university-career-fair)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Mostly out of courtesy and to better organize my schedule. As an intern, I typically do not have sick days. I am not concerned about my future employments or pay.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to "inform" your manager. Just ask for the time off and if asked for a reason you can openly tell them. As your time there is limited it is expected of you that you organize your future engagements.

Apart from that, it does not hurt to let your colleagues/superiors know what you are up to, professionally, as a networking aspect. *"Oh, we need a good Programmer, didn´t we have this intern, Ben, two years ago who also worked for Big-X - I wonder what he is up to?"*

Answer (score 0):

I'd add that if your new employer is going to check references than you absolutely must tell whoever the new employer may call about what you're doing. You never want a potential new employer to call your current employer to inquire about you and your current employer replying, "Oh wow, I didn't even know Ben was [looking for another position] / [listing me as his reference]."